# cannot type umlaut (äöü) in R Studio on one of two computers with identical R and RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have two computers with Win10 pro 64 and the same versions of R and RStudio installed.

On one computer, I cannot type umlauts like "üäö" in the RStudio console.

comuter 1: `>üäö`

computer2: `>ZZZ`

I've been trying to solve that problem for hours now. Has anybody had the same problem?

These are the installation details (same on both computers):

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          4.3
>   year           2017
>   month          11
>   day            30
>   svn rev        73796
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
>   nickname       Kite-Eating Tree

RStudio:

> > RStudio.Version() $citation
>
> To cite RStudio in publications use:
>
> RStudio Team (2016). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio,
>   Inc., Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.
>
> A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is
>
> @Manual{,
>       title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
>       author = {{RStudio Team}},
>       organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
>       address = {Boston, MA},
>       year = {2016},
>       url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},   }
>
> $mode [1] "desktop"
>
> $version [1] ‘1.1.442’

`Sys.getlocale()` gives on both computers

> [1]
>   "LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252"

I tried to:

- reinstall R
- reinstall RStudio
- language for unicode incompatible programs is set to "Detusch (Schweiz) on both computers
- Reopen with Encoding is set to UTF-8 on both computers.

I can type umlauts in Word and other programs without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the reason: Editor Font in >Tools>Global Options>Appearance was strangely set to "8514oem"... everything works well with "Lucida Console" :D

https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/2imdyu/random_chinese_characters_appearing_in_console/